# getting satellite video stream for Android/windows app

Tags: linux, android, mirror

I have an Android satellite receiver in my house. The device has an app that enables me to play live video that is playing on the device to be displayed on my phone. I traced the app packets and found out that it's using port `49152`. I reached this XML file: [screenshot link](https://ibb.co/pZzS9YJ)

I tried many different solutions to use Mirror Cast with other apps, but all of them tried to use the other port of the device, `port 25806`, which is a UPNP service that loads the device's local folders.

Do you have any idea how I can use Mirror Cast to watch the server on my device? Or how to make a custom service to run this home server?

Comment: High ports sadly tell us next to nothing about content. Can you explain what you mean with "inspected a route" (which is a data link layer thing) and "reached a file" (which is many layers further up? Also, what was in that XML file? What is Mirror Cast? Or do you mean Mira Cast (which is an android thing)?

Comment: I inspected the inner app traffic with the scanner app and reached an IP address with XML file which is this:[Link](https://ibb.co/pZzS9YJ)

Comment: Please don't add screenshots of text, instead add the text to your question - there's a code formatting button for that purpose

Comment: @sinabala I tried to add XML to my question, but the website didn't allow me and it says "spam detected"

Comment: user8744711 you need to format the XML block as code with the `{}` button